# Removing item from array and add it to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am displaying to the user a series of divs with content in them and the user is able to remove the div from the page so that they no longer see it.

I would like to take the same div content that was removed from an array and add it into another array that will be used to populate a dropdown list.

this is what i have:

```
//Remove function
removeCategory(index: number): void {
    this.categories.splice(index, 1);
}
//Array
categories: Array<Item> = [
    new Item(1, 'test1'),
    new Item(2, 'test2')
];
//New Array to add previous removed item
ddoptions: Array<object> = [];
```

Is it possible to do a push statement before the splice in the removeCategory function? I am not sure of what to pass in since doing this gives me an error:

```
this.ddoptions.push(index);
```

Comment: Just take a look at what [`splice` returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). The code above is too fragmentary to show you exactly where to put it, but that should be more than enough to get you there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated for 2020**

With the newer ES specifications you can also use the destructuring assignment operator on an array, which means you don't have to use `concat` or `apply` a `push` function in a given context. This was actually around at the time I wrote this originally, but it's far more common to see now.

```
this.ddoptions.push(...this.categories.splice(index, 1));
```

However the rules from below still apply, using `push` and `splice` will mutate existing arrays, so `concat` should probably still be used if you want immutability.

---

**Original Answer**

You can splice into the push method directly, as splice returns the removed object.

```
this.ddoptions.push(this.categories.splice(index, 1)[0]);
```

The splice method actually returns an array of elements that were removed. In your case, you are only removing one so the above code works. If you are removing one or more elements, you can add these to the second array with several methods.

By using concat to generate a new array:

```
this.ddoptions = this.ddoptions.concat(this.categories.splice(index, 1));
```

This may break things because ddoptions is no longer the same object. It depends on what you're doing and what angular is doing.

You can pass the array as multiple arguments to push by applying the push prototype.

```
[].push.apply(this.ddoptions, this.categories.splice(index, 1));
```

In this way ddoptions will remain as the same array and will push all new elements into it.

Comment: This should work. Although the first one would fit his needs i think.

Answer (score 3):

`Array#splice` conveniently returns an array containing the deleted elements:

```
removeCategory (index) {
  this.ddoptions.push( this.categories.splice(index, 1)[0] )
}
```

---

### [View TypeScript Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Item%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20string)%20%7B%20return%20%5Ba%2C%20b%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20removeCategory(index%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.ddoptions.push(this.categories.splice(index%2C%201)%5B0%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2FArray%0D%0A%20%20categories%3A%20Array%3CItem%3E%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Item(1%2C%20%27test1%27)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Item(2%2C%20%27test2%27)%0D%0A%20%20%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2FNew%20Array%20to%20add%20previous%20removed%20item%0D%0A%20%20ddoptions%3A%20Array%3Cobject%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20example%20%3D%20new%20Example%0D%0A%0D%0Aexample.removeCategory(1)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(example.ddoptions))

---

### JavaScript Demo:

```js
class Item {
  constructor(a, b) { return [a, b] }
}

class Example {
  removeCategory (index) {
    this.ddoptions.push( this.categories.splice(index, 1)[0] )
  }
  //Array
  categories = [
    new Item(1, 'test1'),
    new Item(2, 'test2')
  ]
  //New Array to add previous removed item
  ddoptions = []
}

var example = new Example()

example.removeCategory(1)

console.log(example.ddoptions)
```

Answer (score 2):

Splice returns an array of the deleted elements. You could maybe add a size test of the array, to be sure there is an element inside..

```
//Remove function
removeCategory(index: number): void {
    var deletedElement = this.categories.splice(index, 1);
    ddoptions.push(deletedElement[0]);
}
```